# How to filter menu in Context Menu Jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, css, contextmenu

i have the following script which i used.

I am using the jqquery context menu

here's my script

```
$(function(){
    $.contextMenu({
        selector: '.context-menu-icon, .context-menu-text', 
        build: function($trigger, e) {
            // this callback is executed every time the menu is to be shown
            // its results are destroyed every time the menu is hidden
            // e is the original contextmenu event, containing e.pageX and e.pageY (amongst other data)
            return {
                callback: function(key, options) 
                {
                    if(key=='delete')
                        $(this).remove();
                    if(key=='resize')
                        $(this).resizable();
                    if(key=='edit')
                    {
                        var content = $(this).find('.edit_text').text();


                        var inside_div_id = $(this).find('.edit_text').attr("id");
                        alert(inside_div_id);

                        var width = $(this).width() -1;
                        var height = $(this).height() - 4;

                        var $editbox = $("<input type='text'" + 
                                        "style='width:" + width + ";" +
                                        "height:" + height + ";" +
                                        "border:none" +                           
                                        "' value='" +  content + "' />");          


                        $(this).find('.edit_text').empty();            
                        $(this).find('.edit_text').prepend($editbox);             
                        $editbox.focus();
                        $editbox.select();


                         $($editbox).bind("blur",
                                        function()
                                        {
                                            //$(this).closest('.edit_text').html($($editbox).val());
                                            $('#'+inside_div_id).html($($editbox).val());
                                            $($editbox).remove();
                                        });
                    }   
                },
                items: {
                    "edit": {name: "Edit", icon: "edit"},
                    "resize": {name: "Resize", icon: "resize"},
                    "copy": {name: "Copy", icon: "copy"},
                    "paste": {name: "Paste", icon: "paste"},
                    "delete": {name: "Delete", icon: "delete"},
                    "sep1": "---------",
                    "quit": {name: "Quit", icon: "quit"}
                }
            };
        }
    });
});
```

As u all can see i have two selectors

```
selector: '.context-menu-icon, .context-menu-text',
```

and have the following menu

```
items: {
         "edit": {name: "Edit", icon: "edit"},
         "resize": {name: "Resize", icon: "resize"},
         "copy": {name: "Copy", icon: "copy"},
         "paste": {name: "Paste", icon: "paste"},
         "delete": {name: "Delete", icon: "delete"},
         "sep1": "---------",
         "quit": {name: "Quit", icon: "quit"}
       }
```

Now the problem is that, i want the following menus

```
"edit": {name: "Edit", icon: "edit"},
"resize": {name: "Resize", icon: "resize"},
```

should not be available for the selector `context-menu-icon`

How can i achieve this
?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using below code.

In build event you can get hold of element on which right click is made, check  conditions by using that element's classname and then add and remove menu items into the contextmenu.

```
$(function () {
        var items={
            "edit": { name: "Edit", icon: "edit", disabled: false },
            "cut": { name: "Cut", icon: "cut" },
            "copy": { name: "Copy", icon: "copy" },
            "paste": { name: "Paste", icon: "paste" },
            "delete": { name: "Delete", icon: "delete", disabled: false },
            "sep1": "---------",
            "quit": { name: "Quit", icon: "quit" }
        };
        $.contextMenu({
            selector: '.common',
            callback: function (key, options) {
                var m = "clicked: " + key;
                window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m);
            },
            build: function ($trigger, e) {
                if ($(e.currentTarget).hasClass('green-div')) {
                    if (!e.data.items.edit || !e.data.items.delete) {
                        $.each(items, function (i) {
                            e.data.items[i] = items[i];
                        });
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (e.data.items.edit) {
                        delete e.data.items.edit;
                    }
                    if (e.data.items.delete) {
                        delete e.data.items.delete;
                    }
                }
            },
            items: items
        });
    });
```

fiddle sample [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/96pb5z2p/3/) ,

But in this all items need to be refreshed each and every time , there is some other contextmenu plugin [jQ-UI-ContextMenu](http://jqfaq.com/jquery-ui-context-menu-plugin/)  do the same thing in little easier way.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var liCount = 1;
    $(".parent").jQContextMenu({
        selector: ".showMenu",
        target: "#menu",
                beforeContextMenu: function (context, e) {
                    var element = $(e.element);
                    var editLi = $("li:contains('Edit')", element);
                    var optionsLi = $("li:contains('Other Options')", element);

                    if (context[0].id == "contentDiv1") {
                        //Removing an exsisting menu item.
                        element.find('.dynamicLi').remove();
                        //Adding a new menu item.
                        element.append("<li class='dynamicLi'>Dynamic Item " + liCount + "</li>");

                        //Disabling specific menu item.
                        if (!editLi.hasClass('ui-state-disabled'))
                            editLi.addClass('ui-state-disabled');

                        //Hiding an menu item.
                        if (optionsLi.css('display') != 'none')
                            optionsLi.css('display', 'none');

                        e.refresh();
                        liCount++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        element.find('.dynamicLi').remove();
                        //Enabling specific menu item.
                        if (editLi.hasClass('ui-state-disabled'))
                            editLi.removeClass('ui-state-disabled');

                        //Showing an menu item.
                        if (optionsLi.css('display') == 'none')
                            optionsLi.css('display', 'list-item');
                    }
                },
                itemClick: function (event, ui) {
                    var text = $(ui.items[0]).text();
                    if (event[0].id == "contentDiv1")
                        alert("You clicked on " + text + " in DIV " + 1);
                    else
                        alert("You clicked on " + text + " in DIV " + 2);
                }
    });
});
```

Check out this demo [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sjo1gkz2/4/light/)